# How can I use a JS regex to validate whole numbers with an optional "+" or "-" prefix at the start but not at the end of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

*Note: Not a repeat of any question I could find.*

I need a regex to allow these conditions:

```
1234.789  // Invalid (as it contains decimal)
+1234.789 // Invalid (as it contains decimal again)
12345678+ // Invalid (as it contains + in the end)
+1234324  // valid
```

I have tried a lot of options and I could write a regex which allows only numbers and `+` at the beginning alone but couldn't combine both.

- `/[^\+]+$/`

  `+` allowed only at the end
- `/^[0-9]*[0-9]*$/`

  Only numbers, no +/- symbols.

I need help in getting both combined.

Comment: To match digits followed by `+` or `-`, you can use `^[+-]\d+$`. To make the signs optional use `?` after character clase `^[+-]?\d+$`

Comment: Can u provide a fiddle this doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/yE0kP7/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use Character Classes and Anchoring

In JavaScript, you don't have `\A` or `\z` atoms, so you have to anchor with either `^`, `$`, or `\b` as needed. For example, this regex will work with your corpus:

```
/^[+-]?\d+$/
```

If you have trailing spaces, or other irregularities in your real input, then you'll have to adjust the regular expression accordingly. However, this should get you started.

### Sample Code

You can test it yourself on your sample input. For example:

```
[
    '1234.789',
    '+1234.789',
    '12345678+',
    '+1234324',
    '-1234324',
    '12345789'
].forEach(function (str) {
    var result = str.match(/^[+-]?\d+$/);
    if (result) {
        console.log('  valid: ' + result);
    } else {
        console.log('invalid: ' + str);
    };
});
```

### Output

The code above yields the expected results:

```
invalid: 1234.789
invalid: +1234.789
invalid: 12345678+
  valid: +1234324
  valid: -1234324
  valid: 12345789
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify + or - as an option 0 or 1 times (`[+-]{0,1}`) then digits one or more times (`\d+`). Put them together, and the regex would look like this:

```
[+-]{0,1}\d+
```

Comment: You can change `{0,1}` to `?`; but 1+.

Comment: Naa can u give me a fiddle i tried and this doesnt seem to work for me

Comment: use anchors, `^[+-]?\d+$`